# "Gmailify is not available for this provider." for custom domain

Tags: dns, gmail, imap, pop3

I've bought a domain on gandi.net  and get a mail account with custom domain name. I tried to link my mail account with Gmailify and got the following message:
**Gmailify is not available for this provider.**

I am pretty sure that the IMAP setting is on. I successfully linked the account with gmail android app IMAP option. However, I couldn't link with PC Gmailify option. I think the problem is that the android app allow me to set the mail provider to mail.gandi.net but gmailify auto detect the mail provider with my domain name.

I definitely don't want to use POP3. Is there any other option using IMAP in gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I am not Google Support but Gmailify does not work as an IMAP connection.  It only works with a few email providers but not with custom domains.  To fetch messages from your custom domain, you will need to use POP, but be aware that all your email will disappear from your custom server. That is the way POP works.